# problem with going back to last activity via custom back button

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have a custom back button that for the time being does nothing other than going to the previous activity on the back stack. Heres the code for the button :

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
       {
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
              System.out.println("!!! BACK !!!");
              finishActivity(0);
           }
       });
```

The problem is, its not working. There is simply no change.

Can anyone kindly tell me what I have done wrong here ? Thanks.

Comment: works with this code, though ::  `onBackPressed()`

Comment: I would check the `logcat` to see what exactly is happening.  On an unrelated note, why are you creating a button that does the exact same thing as the built-in back button?

Answer (score 2):

***finishActivity*** finishes an activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(), it doesn't finish the activity you are currently in - **finish()** does that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) instead of `finishActivity()`.

[`finishActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) forces an activity that you started via `startActivityForResult()` to quit, it doesn't finish the current activity. You can also use `onBackPressed()`, that just calls `finish()` internally (see the [default implementation](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/Activity.java&q=activity%20package%3aandroid&type=cs&l=1919)), so it has the same effect. Useful if you override the back button behaviour though.